# Why do I constantly get ActivityNotFound exceptions?

Tags: android, exception, android-activity

I'm a novice Android programmer, and to help me understand how Intents really work, I wanted to put together a small Activity which would let the user call startActivity() with any action and data they want.  I tried many different combinations, including "android.intent.action.VIEW" and "http://www.google.com".  No matter what combinations I use, I always get an ActivityNotFoundException.  Any ideas as to why?

The code in my only Activity is below:

```
public class TestingIntents extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button goButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        goButton.setOnClickListener(new ClickListener());
    }

    private class ClickListener implements OnClickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            String id = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.intent)).getText().toString();
            String data = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.data)).getText().toString();

            Builder builder = new Builder();
            builder = builder.path(data);

            Uri path = builder.build();

            Intent i = new Intent(id, path);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

The results of adb shell logcat from the time of starting the app to just after touching 'Force close' are below.

```
I/ActivityManager( 1086):
 Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.
MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=tk.h2g2guy.testin
gIntents/.TestingIntents }
I/ActivityManager( 1086): Start proc tk.h2g2guy.testingIntents for activity tk.h
2g2guy.testingIntents/.TestingIntents: pid=4037 uid=10054 gids={}
D/dalvikvm( 1006): GC_EXPLICIT freed 289 objects / 10960 bytes in 98ms
D/dalvikvm( 1006): GC_EXPLICIT freed 47 objects / 2088 bytes in 121ms
D/dalvikvm( 1006): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2 objects / 48 bytes in 109ms
I/ActivityManager( 1086): Displayed activity tk.h2g2guy.testingIntents/.TestingI
ntents: 462 ms (total 462 ms)
D/dalvikvm( 2300): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1226 objects / 61640 bytes in 69ms
I/ActivityManager( 1086): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.
VIEW dat=http%3A//www.google.com }
D/AndroidRuntime( 4037): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 4037): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4
001d7e0)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4037): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 4037): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity
found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http%3A//www.google.
com }
E/AndroidRuntime( 4037):        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivit
yResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4037):        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity
(Instrumentation.java:1378)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4037):        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(A
ctivity.java:2817)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4037):        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.j
ava:2923)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4037):        at tk.h2g2guy.testingIntents.TestingIntents$Clic
kListener.onClick(TestingIntents.java:41)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4037):        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408
)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4037):        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:
8816)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4037):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.jav
a:587)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4037):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.ja
va:92)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4037):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4037):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThrea
d.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4037):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4037):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:5
21)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4037):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndA
rgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4037):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zygot
eInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4037):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

W/ActivityManager( 1086):   Force finishing activity tk.h2g2guy.testingIntents/.
TestingIntents
W/ActivityManager( 1086): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{449d4518 tk.h
2g2guy.testingIntents/.TestingIntents}
I/Process ( 4037): Sending signal. PID: 4037 SIG: 9
I/ActivityManager( 1086): Process tk.h2g2guy.testingIntents (pid 4037) has died.

I/WindowManager( 1086): WIN DEATH: Window{44bd4120 tk.h2g2guy.testingIntents/tk.
h2g2guy.testingIntents.TestingIntents paused=false}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried many different combinations,
>   including
>   "android.intents.action.VIEW" and
>   "html://www.google.com".

`android.intents.action.VIEW` is not a valid activity action. You probably want to drop the `s`.

`html://www.google.com` is not a valid URL. You probably want to replace the `html://` with `http://`.

Comment: And...that's what happens when you don't proofread.  Thanks for pointing that out, but I actually used the correct forms in the application.  Still doesn't work.

Comment: @Mrrvomun: Delete all references to `Builder` (you don't need it) and just put the typed-in text into the `Intent`.

Comment: You mean for the data parameter?  Eclipse gives me an error, and I can't find a constructor that is passed two strings.  The setData method requires a Uri object, too.

Comment: @Mrrvomun: `Uri.parse()` converts a `String` into a `Uri`.

Comment: Problem solved!  I think `Uri.Builder` was converting the colon after `http` into the ampersand code.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Check your logs with:

```
adb shell logcat
```

But I guess you are missing the definition of your `Activity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: The main and only Activity is in the AndroidManifest.xml file.  I'm working in Eclipse, so I'm pretty sure that isn't screwed up.