# Activity not found exception

Tags: android

- I am getting activityNotFound Exception.Unable to find explicit
  activity class.But I have declared my activity in manifest.
- I searched a lot of SO post regarding to this issue.But it doesn't
  solved my problem.

**StackTrace:**

```
07-06 23:52:27.226: E/AndroidRuntime(7600): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-06 23:52:27.226: E/AndroidRuntime(7600): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.stevedata/android.app.ListActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
07-06 23:52:27.226: E/AndroidRuntime(7600):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
07-06 23:52:27.226: E/AndroidRuntime(7600):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
07-06 23:52:27.226: E/AndroidRuntime(7600):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
07-06 23:52:27.226: E/AndroidRuntime(7600):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
07-06 23:52:27.226: E/AndroidRuntime(7600):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3587)
07-06 23:52:27.226: E/AndroidRuntime(7600):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3555)
07-06 23:52:27.226: E/AndroidRuntime(7600):     at com.example.stevedata.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:38)
07-06 23:52:27.226: E/AndroidRuntime(7600):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
07-06 23:52:27.226: E/AndroidRuntime(7600):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
07-06 23:52:27.226: E/AndroidRuntime(7600):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-06 23:52:27.226: E/AndroidRuntime(7600):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-06 23:52:27.226: E/AndroidRuntime(7600):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-06 23:52:27.226: E/AndroidRuntime(7600):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-06 23:52:27.226: E/AndroidRuntime(7600):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 23:52:27.226: E/AndroidRuntime(7600):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-06 23:52:27.226: E/AndroidRuntime(7600):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-06 23:52:27.226: E/AndroidRuntime(7600):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-06 23:52:27.226: E/AndroidRuntime(7600):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    Button button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListActivity.class);

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

  }

 }
```

**ListActivity.java:**

```
public class ListActivity extends Activity {

    Button button1;

      @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.list_activity);

            button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
      }
}
```

**Manifest:**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> 

      <activity  
          android:name=".ListActivity" 
           android:label="@string/app_name"
          />

</application>
```

Anyone can help me with this.Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I constantly get ActivityNotFound exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436733/why-do-i-constantly-get-activitynotfound-exceptions)

Comment: Your app is trying to access the class com.example.stevedata/android.app.ListActivity which looks strange. Could you try using the complete file name like com.example.stevedata.ListActivity and see if the issue persists. If that doesn't help, try using a different name for your ListActivity class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your activity name is **ListActivity**, which is a class already on android (`android.app.ListActivity`). So **rename** the class name.

Comment: Worked successfully.Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you imported the wrong `ListActivity` in you're `MainActivity`. The crash indicates that you are trying to start `android.app.ListActivity`

Answer (score 2):

I think the root cause because of Android SDK existing a Class name [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) So the Os did not know exaclty what class need to be called this case.
Try to rename your class to another in both of `java` and `Manifest`

Answer (score 1):

Import `com.example.stevedata.ListActivity` instead of `android.app.ListActivity` in your `MainActivity`